# Code to list all maximal bicliques of a bipartite graph

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory

We are looking for a code to list all maximal bicliques in bipartite graphs efficiently, as we want to run it on (large and sparse) graphs, with up to roughly a million nodes and edges in no more that a few hours.

In the literature, we know [this fast implementation](https://github.com/S1mpleCod/cohesive_subgraph_bipartite) which implements the algorithm presented in ["Efficient Maximal Biclique Enumeration for Large Sparse Bipartite Graphs"](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/https://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol15/p1559-chen.pdf) by Chen et al. (2022).
It is state-of-the-art as far as we know.

Unfortunately, it does not enumerate maximal bicliques but count them, and it seems very tricky to change the code in order to explicitly list the bicliques.

A slightly less efficient implementation would be sufficient but we need to have the explicit enumeration of the maximal bicliques. Does anyone have a suggestion?

note: this is a copy of [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/161849/code-to-list-all-maximal-bicliques-of-a-bipartite-graph) post on SE Computer science, I am not sure which of the two sites is the most appropriate for this question